# A basic question on equilibrium point of coupled differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The system of ordinary differential equations given by

$$ \dot{x_1}(t)= k + \sin(x_1 + x_2) + x_1$$
$$ \dot{x_2}(t)= k + \sin(x_1 + x_2) - x_1$$

do not have any equilibrium point for $k >1$.  Why ?

Comment: @Amzoti: sorry, trivial, I got confused with two equations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, if the question is still actual, or not. So, assume that there exists some equilibrium point $(x_1, x_2)$, i.e., in this point we have
$$
k + \sin(x_1 + x_2) + x_1 = 0,\\
k + \sin(x_1 + x_2) - x_1 = 0.
$$
Subtracting one equation from another, we get
$$
2 x_1 = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x_1 = 0.
$$
Hence, 
$$
k + \sin x_2 = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \sin x_2 = -k,
$$
which is impossible, if $k > 1$.